# invalid mode chmod command

Tags: chmod

I am trying to look for all files with xyz in their filenames in my working directory and then change their permissions in symbolic mode.

```
find . -type f -name *xyz* ; chmod -v u=a+wx {}\;
```

I get an error:

```
chmod: invalid mode: ‘–v’
Try 'chmod --help' for more information.
```

when I remove the `-v`, I get the same error. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: find . -type f -name *xyz* ; chmod -v u=a+wx {} \;   I forgot to show the space. It shows the same error.

Comment: You can edit posts.

Comment: maybe you just want `chmod a+wx` ? "a" includes "u" (and "g" and "o").

Comment: Also some more info on distribution, bash version etc. would help us help you. Also, you might want to try `--exec` instead of the non-escaped semicolon. Could be that you `chmod` simply does not support this feature, you might want to try `chattr` instead.

Comment: first get your `chmod` working properly on one file, before you trawl through the directory using find.

Answer (score 2):

The find -exec syntax is:

```
find … -exec command {} \;
```

you've instead got a `;` instead of `-exec` and you need a space between `{}` and `\;`.

Finally, your mode is, err, not right. Maybe you were going for `u=,a+wx`—remove all permissions for the owner, then give everyone write and execute? Which results in `-wx-wx-wx`, an odd set of permissions. No idea what permissions you intended.